# How to break from `__main__` without exit()

Tags: python

I'm doing python coding with Emacs.

I find it troublesome to get Emacs inferior shell exited whenever I call `sys.exit`. How can the code break from `__main__` block without killing Emacs inferior shell process, without introducing another indented block?

```
if __name__ == "__main__":
    # doing something
    if args.init:
        init_env(cfg_dict, args)
        exit(0)   # <--- this kills the Emacs sub-shell
    # otherwise doing something
    # ...
```

P.S. I slept on the title of this question for a while, but I couldn't think of better title. :-(

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Why not wrap the main code in a function and make use of `return`:

```
def main():
    # doing something
    if args.init:
        init_env(cfg_dict, args)
        return

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```